# [MySql]How to copy a row from one table to another and fill additional columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

So I want to condense this query and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Right now I use

```
$move_to_sold = 
    "INSERT INTO sold_inv_item(
        `sku`,
        `designer`,
        `type`,
        `price`,
        `metal_type`,
        `stone_type`,
        `stone_weight`,
        `item_desc`,
        `item_img`
    )
    SELECT
        `sku`,
        `designer`,
        `type`,
        `price`,
        `metal_type`,
        `stone_type`,
        `stone_weight`,
        `item_desc`,
        `item_img`
    FROM inv_item
    WHERE `sku` = '$sku'";

$add_date_and_name = 
    "UPDATE sold_inv_item 
    SET `purchase_date` = '$date', `customer_name` = '$name' 
    WHERE `sku` = '$sku'";
```

what I'm trying to do is copy a row from 1 table to another, and then add additional data into the 2 extra columns from $_POST data.

I tried something like

```
INSERT INTO sold_inv_item(`sku`,`designer`,`type`,`price`,`metal_type`,
`stone_type`,`stone_weight`,`item_desc`,`item_img`,`purchase_date`,`customer_name`) 

VALUES ((select `sku`,`designer`,`type`,`price`,`metal_type`,
`stone_type`,`stone_weight`,`item_desc`,`item_img` FROM inv_item WHERE inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'), '2019-02-14','betty Girl');
```

This gives a column mismatch error, I suspect because it's trying to fit all the rows into 1 column instead of spreading them out.

Finally this works but I'd rather do something like the middle solution if possible.

```
INSERT INTO sold_inv_item(`sku`,`designer`,`type`,`price`,`metal_type`,
`stone_type`,`stone_weight`,`item_desc`,`item_img`,`purchase_date`,`customer_name`) 

VALUES ((select `sku` from inv_item where inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'),
        (select `designer` from inv_item where inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'),
        (select `type` from inv_item where inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'),
        (select `price` from inv_item where inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'),
        (select `metal_type` from inv_item where inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'),
        (select `stone_type` from inv_item where inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'),
        (select `stone_weight` from inv_item where inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'),
        (select `item_desc` from inv_item where inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'),
        (select `item_img` from inv_item where inv_item.sku = 'pepsi-2-tone'),'2019-02-14','betty Girl');
```

So finally the question is, what is the most effective way code and performance wise to copy a row from one table to another and fill additional columns. 
There a few similar ones but none that I can find cover more than 1-2 columns being copied over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax, like :

```
INSERT INTO sold_inv_item (
    `sku`,
    `designer`,
    `type`,
    `price`,
    `metal_type`,
    `stone_type`,
    `stone_weight`,
    `item_desc`,
    `item_img`, 
    `purchase_date`, 
    `customer_name`
)
SELECT 
    `sku`,
    `designer`,
     `type`,
     `price`,
     `metal_type`,
     `stone_type`,
     `stone_weight`,
     `item_desc`,
     `item_img`,
     :date,
     :name
FROM inv_item
WHERE `sku` = :sku
```

PS : when it comes to using `POST`ed parameters in SQL queries, anyone on SO will strongly suggest to [**use prepared statements and parameterized queries**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), to protect your code from SQL injection and make your queries more efficient, readable and maintainable. I modified the query to use named parameters.

Comment: This works, I didn't know you could add variables that didn't exist in the table you're pulling from directly to a select. Thanks!

Comment: Ya, I'm just getting the logic down. I'll convert this to a prepared query when it goes to code.

Comment: @Purgedmoon : exactly. Then you can prepare the statement once, and reuse it multiple times as needed.